# Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils

Tags: maven, cxf, spring-ws

I'm developing an application using Spring/Maven and I'm experiencing a problem with a dependency. Everything was working but when I added a dependency to Spring-WS, my tests stopped working.

Here is the stacktrace I have, leading to a **Failed to load ApplicationContext**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:256)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:98)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.mycompany.webservice.documentservice.client.DocumentServiceService.<init>(DocumentServiceService.java:61)
    at com.mycompany.service.implementation.DocumentService.<init>(DocumentService.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
```

And here is the new dependencies :

```
<!-- 
    Spring WS
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I think there is a conflict with CXF dependencies but can't find where :

```
<!-- 
    Web Service
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the conflicts, but when I add an exclusion the problem still occurs
[image: Conflict with wsdl4j]
[image: Conflict with wss4j]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed the issue by doing the following :

Upgrade from CXF 2.7.6 to 2.7.7
Add dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
    <version>${sjsxp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Can't explain why but the tests run well and the application too.

Comment: You really don't want to use sjsxp if you can at all avoid it.   Make sure you have woodstox-core 4.2.0 pulled in someplace.